# i have a list of images and images shape is (50,50,3) . how to convert into numpy.ndarray of shape (19929,50,50,3)

Tags: arrays, list, numpy

```
train_x=[]
val_x=[]
test_x=[]
for image in train_list:
    train_x.append(skimage.data.imread(image))
for image in val_list:
    val_x.append(skimage.data.imread(image))
for image in test_list:
    test_x.append(skimage.data.imread(image))
```

how to convert train_x list to ndarray of shape (len(train_x),50,50,3).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.stack()`:

```
import numpy as np
arrs = [np.random.randn(10, 11, 3) for i in range(5)]
arr = np.stack(arrs, axis=0)
print(arr.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import numpy as np
    import skimage
    train_x=[]
    val_x=[]
    test_x=[]
    for image in train_list:
        train_x.append(skimage.data.imread(image))

    for image in val_list:
        val_x.append(skimage.data.imread(image))

    for image in test_list:
        test_x.append(skimage.data.imread(image))

    train_x=np.array(train_x)
    val_x=np.array(val_x)
    test_x=np.array(text_x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can preallocate an empty array and fill it with `train_x` elements (I suppose `numpy.stack()` function does the same behind the scene):

```
import numpy as np

train_x = [np.random.randn(50, 50, 3) for _ in range(1000)] #dummy x_train

big_arr = np.empty([len(train_x), 50, 50, 3])
big_arr[:,...] = train_x[:]
```

In this case, the reason I pick this way against `stack` is its flexibility. It may be impossible to have both `train_x` and `big_arr` in memory (may cause memory overflow). So if you are obliged to have a array shaped `(19929,50,50,3)` in memory for processing, try to do so:

```
big_arr = np.empty([len(train_list), 50, 50, 3])
for i, image in enumerate(train_list):
    big_arr[i,:,:,:] = skimage.data.imread(image)  # read directly from hard disc and fill the array
```

Comment: List append doesn't have those speed or memory problems.   Speed's similar to your write to a preallocated array.